# Count number of groups

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a long column of names and I want to count the number of types of names in each column.

Here's an example:

[image: Input]

You can see that I have 3 types of different names here.
Therefore, the output for this example would be 3.

[image: Output in A9 cell]

Comment: There are plenty of examples in this forum of how to do that.  And it is somewhat dependent on your version of Excel.  If you have the latest version, it is as simple as `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(myRange))`.  If you don't, do a little research and post back with any issues.

Comment: In addition to the formulas, you may paste the whole column to other location, `go to Data tab use Remove Duplicates in Data Tools group`, it will tells you how many unique values remain at last. Please note the blank in source data will affects the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is for **Excel 365**.

With data in column **A**, try the formula:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A))))
```

[image]

If you have an older version of Excel, you can use a variation of :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A<>"")/COUNTIF(A:A,A:A & ""))
```

This formula will exclude blank cells from the sum, but it is extremely slow.  To improve performance use something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A99<>"")/COUNTIF(A1:A99,A1:A99 & ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

*My approach is little different, therefore I would like to suggest 3 different formula to count Group, if are `Count both Text & Number`, `Counts Only Text` and `Counts Only Numbers`.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `I31`:

  `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(I$21:I$29,I$21:I$29&""))`
- Formula in cell `J31`:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((ISTEXT(K21:K29))/COUNTIF(K21:K29,K21:K29&""))
  ```
- Formula in cell `K31`:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(K$21:K$29))/COUNTIF(K$21:K$29,K$21:K$29&""))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*